# Bytes sent/received for Node.js HTTP request

Tags: node.js

Once an HTTP request has been served, I would like to log the number of bytes sent/received.

A simple source for this data is `req.connection.bytesRead`/`.bytesWritten`.  However, this is problematic for HTTP 1.1 keep-alive connections, as the same socket can be used for multiple requests.  **I need to log per-request, not per-connection.**

The solution must lie on the HTTP side of things, but I see no methods documented for getting the data I need.

What is the proper way to calculate bytes read/written for HTTP requests served by Node.js's `http.Server`?

Comment: You do have a `Content-Length` header on both requests and responses, if that's something node.js lets you access. It excludes headers thought.

Comment: @zneak, Good idea.  Unfortunately, I need to include the header/footer lengths.  I suppose I could reconstruct them.  My application is also not sending a `Content-Length` header, as I am sending streaming media.  Although since that means I am sending `Connection: close`, I may not have to worry about keep-alive connections after all.  In any case, I am still wondering if there is another way, possibly undocumented.  I will probably dig into Node.js's http.js tonight.

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately, I never found a proper way to do this.  I've resorted some fairly terrible duck punching, but it works for my particular use case.  In case anyone else stumbles along with this problem, you can start with this and refine from there.

### Module #1:  "Extra Events"

All this module does is make the response object emit a `finishBeforeSocketDestroy` event.  Since I needed this event in a few places in my application, I effectively made a separate module just for this duck punch.  `app.use()` it before Module #2.

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    var end = res.end;

    res.end = function () {
        res.end = end;
        res.emit('finishBeforeSocketDestroy');
        res.end.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    next();
}
```

### Module #2: "Stats"

This module creates a `req.stats` object, containing all sorts of useful goodies for tracking bandwidth usage during usage of the connection, and after it is finished.

```
var pollTime = 1000;
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    var pollInterval;

    function pollStats () {
        if (typeof req.stats._lastMeasuredTime === 'object') {
            var secondsSinceLastMeasurement = ((new Date() - req.stats._lastMeasuredTime) / 1000);
            req.stats.averageRate = {
                read: (req.socket.bytesRead - req.stats.bytesRead) / secondsSinceLastMeasurement,
                write: (req.socket.bytesWritten - req.stats.bytesWritten) / secondsSinceLastMeasurement
            };
        }
        req.stats._lastMeasuredTime = new Date();
        req.stats.bytesRead = req.socket.bytesRead;
        req.stats.bytesWritten = req.socket.bytesWritten;
    }

    req.stats = {
        startTime: new Date(),
        endTime: null,
        averageRate: {read: null, write: null},
        bytesRead: req.socket.bytesRead,
        bytesWritten: req.socket.bytesWritten,
        _lastMeasuredTime: new Date()
    };

    pollInterval = setInterval(pollStats, pollTime);

    res.on('finishBeforeSocketDestroy', function () {
        clearInterval(pollInterval);
        pollStats();
        req.stats.endTime = new Date();
    });

    next();
}
```

Like I said... messy.  I'm only posting it as duck punching may be your only option.  Also beware that `socket` may get re-used for multiple HTTP requests, which could cause you to double-count some bytes if you're not careful.

Comment: This is brilliant!  I need to do something similar (specifically, I want to track bytes sent per request).  Is this available as an npm module?  It should be.  I know you may not be happy about this because of the duck punching, but it is a useful utility.

Comment: @Brandon No, it's not an NPM module, but you're welcome to make one if you would like.  Also note that I've had success with later versions of Node.js and the `finish` event.  My "extra events" middleware doesn't seem to be necessary anymore with later (~>0.10.20) version of Node.js

Comment: Perhaps you don't need to create the extra event yourself, `require('on-finished')` instead? Not much improvement tho.

Comment: @Zlatko Yeah, that module does the same thing that I'm doing here, basically.  It doesn't actually work for the request itself.

Comment: Have anyone found a better way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Furthermore, is this still a problem? I was making a simple test assigning a random value to a `request` object like `req.value = "testing"`, and once making another request, I was trying to print this value `console.log(req.value)`. But this value was always as `undefined`. I was just unlucky or this socket connections are not being reused anymore?

Comment: @GGirotto Each request (regardless of connection) will have its own object.  Also, if you're extending the request object, consider using a `Symbol` instead.  `req[someSymbol].something = ...`

Comment: @Brad I was looking through other similar questions and found a npm module that propose a solution very similar  to yours, but they store the request stats on `req.connection` (https://github.com/watson/request-stats/blob/master/lib/stats_emitter.js). Is there a difference from storing this stats on `req` or in `req.connection`?

Comment: It's probably a better idea to associate with `connection`, since that's where the byte count is being read from.  Each connection can have multiple requests.

Answer (score 3):

Just store traffic value after each response and calculate difference in 'finish' or 'end' handler:

```
// server.onRequest:
  ...
  req._prevBytesWritten = 0;

// response.onFinish/onEnd:
  ...
  responseLen = req.socket.bytesWritten - req._prevBytesWritten;
  req._prevBytesWritten = req.socket.bytesWritten;
```

Comment: I still don't have a good answer for this question, but someone might as well get the bounty.  +200, thanks.

Comment: You generous sir.Is there any way to dump the whole http  request and respone as raw bytes like how its displayed in chrome devtools/ network /headers

Comment: @SachinDivakar for incoming data you can add 'data' event handler to response's socket object. For outgoing data I believe the only way is to proxify `write()` method of request's socket object.